# Blinking underscore after NVIDIA graphics propreitary driver use/install on UBUNTU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card

I have ZOTAC GT730 SYNERGY EDITION 4GB 128BIT DDR3(NVIDIA) graphic card inserted on the slot. As well i have dual boot (windows10-working fine) & (Ubuntu-16.0.4- not working). After ubuntu installation i lost my resolution chooser, there is only two option and both doesnot fit my screen.Then i install the correct version Linux 384.111 or 340.106 version drivers and they didn't work either, perhaps after the proprietary use of the graphic card my ubuntu does not open. It stuck on black dead screen with blinking underscore after splash screen~ windows work fine but to open ubuntu i have to remove driver but also the resolution is same.Please could someone know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Enter the virtual console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. After logging into the console, enter your login and password.
3. First we look, what drivers are in the system:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --get-selections|grep nvidia
   ```
4. Remove all:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia | grep -v deinstall | grep -v common | awk '{print $1}' | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove
   ```
5. Check that everything is deleted:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia | grep -v deinstall | grep -v common
   ```
6. Install only what you need, namely the last / penultimate / pre-penultimate official driver Nvidia from Canonical (the creators of Ubuntu) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-XXXXX
   ```

   where ХХХХХ - is the number of driver
7. If the installation is normal, configure the driver:

   ```
   sudo nvidia-xconfig
   ```
8. Reboot.

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

And later then you can try https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa